# Проблема с переводом в байты

Tags: python, перевод, байты

Вот ошибка - и сразу скажу что я новичок в пайтоне, а задача у меня зашифровать строку. Но сначала была ошибка с переводом в байты, а теперь вот

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 46, in <module>
    encrypted = encrypt(str(data).encode("utf-8"), str(password))
  File "main.py", line 11, in encrypt
    raw = pad(raw)
  File "main.py", line 7, in <lambda>
    pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * chr(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE)
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

Вот мой код

```
import qrcode
import base64
import hashlib
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
BLOCK_SIZE = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * chr(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE)
unpad = lambda s: s[:-ord(s[len(s) - 1:])]
def encrypt(raw, password):
    private_key = hashlib.sha256(password.encode("utf-8")).digest()
    raw = pad(raw)
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))
 
 
def decrypt(enc, password):
    private_key = hashlib.sha256(password.encode("utf-8")).digest()
    enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
    iv = enc[:16]
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[16:]))
print("CryptQR v1")
print("==============================================")
while True:
  lang = input("Choose the language - 1)Russian  2)English: ")
  if (lang == "1"): 
    a = input("Выберите режим - 1)Создание QR  2)Открытие QR: ")
    if (a == "1"): # Создание QR режим - QR Creating Mode
      while True:
        data = input ("Введите текст (до 512 символов): ")
        if (len(data) > 512):
          print("==============================================")
          print("Вы не можете ввести больше 512 символов!")
          print("==============================================")
          continue
        else:
          while True:
            password = input ("Введите пароль (От 16 символов): ")
            if (len(password) < 16):
              print("==============================================")
              print("Вы не можете ввести меньше 16 символов!")
              print("==============================================")
              continue
            else:
              encrypted = encrypt(str(data).encode("utf-8"), str(password))
              filename = "cryptqr.png"
              img = qrcode.make(str(encrypted))
              img.save(filename)
              print("==============================================")
              print("QR-код создан!")
              print("==============================================")
              break
          break
    break
  elif (lang == "2"): # Часть на наглийском - English part
    a = input("Choose mode - 1)Create QR  2)Open QR: ")
    if (a == "1"): # Создание QR режима - QR Creating Mode
      while True:
        data = input ("Enter text (up to 512 characters): ")
        if (len(data) > 512):
          print("==============================================")
          print("You cannot enter more than 512 characters!")
          print("==============================================")
          continue
        else:
          while True:
            password = input ("Enter password (From 16 characters):")
            if (len(password) < 16):
              print("==============================================")
              print("You cannot enter less than 16 characters!")
              print("==============================================")
              continue
            else:
              encrypted = encrypt(str(data), str(password))
              filename = "cryptqr.png"
              img = qrcode.make(str(encrypted))
              img.save(filename)
              print("==============================================")
              print("QR code created successfully!")
              print("==============================================")
              break
          break
    break
  else:
    continue
#pip install --upgrade pip
#pip3 install pycryptodome
```

Comment: В библиотеке pycrypto уже должны быть реализованы функции для padding. Прочитайте её документацию. Также, если Вы новичёк в Python - прочитайте PEP8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * chr(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE).encode()`

Должно решить проблему

Comment: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Comment: @IvanGorincih Вы, случайно, не передаёте в функцию `pad` тип `str` вместо `bytes`? `raw` должен быть `bytes`. Я проверил локально у себя и с `encode()` работает. Добавьте сюда в ответ на мой комментарий ошибку

Comment: import qrcode
import base64
import hashlib
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
BLOCK_SIZE = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * chr(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE).encode()
unpad = lambda s: s[:-ord(s[len(s) - 1:])]
def encrypt(raw, password):
    private_key = hashlib.sha256(password.encode("utf-8")).digest()
    raw = pad(raw)
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))

Вот часть кода - всё правильно?

Comment: @IvanGorincih Похоже правильно, но я попросил ошибку. Так не понять что у Вас (или у меня) пошло не так.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 46, in <module>
    encrypted = encrypt(str(data), str(password))
  File "main.py", line 11, in encrypt
    raw = pad(raw)
  File "main.py", line 7, in <lambda>
    pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * chr(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE).encode()
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Вот такая ошибка

Comment: @IvanGorincih Вы передаёте в функцию `raw` как `str`, а она должна быть `bytes`. Правильным будет: `encrypted = encrypt(str(data).encode(), str(password)) `. Вы вернулись к своей прошлой ошибке :)

Comment: я тебя расцелую!!! Ты меня спас!!! Спасибо тебе!!!

Comment: Только проблема - на выходи перед текстом стоит b' и в конце стоит тоже '  - что с этим делать?

Comment: @IvanGorincih в терминале от функции `print`? Так Python показывает что эта переменная - `bytes`. Декодируйте обрато в `str` с методом `decode`. Например: `print(some_bytes.decode())`. Это базовый вопрос о Python, попробуйте поискать для начала в Google, он сможет предоставить намного более раскрытую информацию о теме чем я в комментариях.

Comment: не - вообще, я в qr закодировал а на выходи остался b``

Comment: получилось - но ещё вопрос остался - я хочу декодировать это всё. и вот как я сделал 

 data = input("Введите зашифрованный текст с QR-кода: ")
      password = input("Введите пароль от данных: ")
      decrypted = decrypt(data, password)
      print("==============================================")
      print("Расшифрованный текст: " + str(decrypt))

Но вот что мне выдало -  Расшифрованный текст: <function decrypt at 0x7f1ad8619f70>